# How to show multiple data columns in one dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show data from 2 database table where their active is `no`, in one dropdownlist. How do I compile the selected data in one dropdownlist?

I'm using `SqlDataSource` from the toolbox

```
SELECT [Desktop_ID], [DTComputerName] FROM [Desktop] WHERE ([DTActive] LIKE '%' + @ DTActive + '%')`

SELECT [Notebook_ID], [NBComputerName] FROM [Notebook] WHERE ([NBActive] LIKE '%' + @ NBActive + '%')
```

I want to show the selected value in a DropDownList from both queries. However, I can only use 1 datasource to show. I am using Visual Studio 17 and SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can use union or union all for that in sql to join result set of multiple select query to single result set.

```
SELECT [Desktop_ID], [DTComputerName] FROM [Desktop] 
       WHERE ([DTActive] LIKE '%' + @ DTActive + '%')`
UNION ALL
SELECT [Notebook_ID], [NBComputerName] FROM [Notebook] 
       WHERE ([NBActive] LIKE '%' + @ NBActive + '%')
```

> Point to Note
>
> - Number of columns in all selection set should be equal.
> - It may be   hard to distinguish which value came from which table as    result are  combined into one result set.

Comment: If you make union statement make field name in both are same either '[Desktop_ID], [DTComputerName] ' or as '[Desktop_ID] as 'id', [DTComputerName] as 'value'

Comment: @Saneeshkunjunni no need to have same column name in union select statements. Final result set will use first select statement column name to render result.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Merge Method In C#.Here is the example of it.It work pretty fine for dropdown list item.

```
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT distinct year FROM daman_reading_2016 ", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select distinct year from daman_reading_2015 ", con);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds1);
        da.Fill(ds);
da1.Fill(ds2);
        ds.Merge(ds1);
ds2.Merge(ds);

        ddlyear.DataSource = ds2;
        ddlyear.DataValueField = "YEAR";
        ddlyear.DataTextField = "YEAR";
        ddlyear.DataBind();
        ddlyear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Year", "0"));
        con.Close();
```